# DownloadManager in Android (xamarin) throw Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

In quite some time now, i have been trying to download a file through [DownloadManager](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.App.DownloadManager). There are lots of examples on how to do that in android, but for xamarin i am not so lucky.

I've created an application with minimal API v15 (4.0.3)  and checked that Mono.Android.dll is referenced. Also added the permissions `INTERNET`and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
DownloadManager dm;
dm =  (DownloadManager)GetSystemService (Context.DownloadService);
DownloadManager.Request request = new  Android.App.DownloadManager.Request (Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("https://www.adress));
request.SetDestinationUri (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY));
var c = dm.Enqueue (request);
```

Every time when i hit `dm.Enqueue (request);` there is an error that occurred:

[image]

I also try to set `SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir`or `SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir` no success.

...oh and this is my directory

> const string EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY =
>   Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath +
>   "/MyAppFolder";

I don't know what am i going wrong,please help me with that.

Comment: According to the stack trace, there is a problem with the URL given. It says "Unknown URL" and then "content://downloads/my_down"...

Comment: well before that i was using a webclient to download exact same files, and everything was ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am kind of ashamed, the issue was that the device had `DownloadManager` app disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the directory path as constant string. But you haven't created the same directory. So you need to create directory and then pass it. Create path like this :

```
public string GetMyAppDir()
{
    var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
    var dir = path.AbsolutePath + File.Separator + "MyAppFolder";
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Then use it :

```
request.SetDestinationUri(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(GetMyAppDir()));
```

Hope it works.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am absolutely sure that the folder exists, even if i implement what you suggest, nothing changes, thanks anyway

Comment: @SeeSharp, I hope you have set all necessary permissions. Then try commenting out your "request.SetDestinationUri (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY));" line, and run again. If it gives any exception or not

Comment: i have tried to create the same application in android studio, the same error occurred `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://`, i am missing something just can't figured out

Comment: have you tried, commenting the SetDestinationUri method??

Comment: :) I told you that because if you don't specify it then it will download it on default folder, so by commenting it you make sure that there is nothing wrong with that part. What is "content/downloads/my_downloads"?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the "Android.Net.Uri.FromFile" bit

```
var dm =  (DownloadManager) GetSystemService (Context.DownloadService);
string webUri = "http://somewhere/some.png";
var dir =  new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/MyAppFolder/");
if (!dir.Exists ())
    dir.Mkdirs ();
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (new Java.IO.File (dir.AbsolutePath+"/my.png"));
var request = new  DownloadManager.Request (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (webUri));
request.SetDestinationUri (uri);
dm.Enqueue (request);
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, but the downloadmanager was enabled and it was depending on the android version if it worked or not. what you get back from the downloadmanager (depending on the android version!) is a URI you still need to resolve. so what i did was i added the following to retreive a file path (file:///path/to/file) from the local uri (content://downloads/my_downloads/123).

like this:

```
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.DownloadService);

            Uri fileUri = downloadManager.GetUriForDownloadedFile(fileReference);

            String uriString = fileUri.ToString();
            var compareResult = String.Compare("content://", 0, uriString, 0, 10);
            if (compareResult == 0)
            {
                String filePath = "";
                String[] filePathColumn = { "_data" };
                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.ContentResolver;
                var cursor = contentResolver.Query(fileUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                filePath = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
                cursor.Close();
                fileUri = Uri.Parse("file://" + filePath);
            }
```